# Format random id to yy-xxxxxxxx

Tags: mysql, vb.net, random

How to format random id numbers to `yy-xxxxxxxx`

first 2 digits are last 2 digits of the current year followed by dash then random numbers***

here's my code:

```
  Public Class frmNewPatient
        Dim MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=PatientManagementSystem;")
        Dim Birthdate, day, month, year As String
        Const RndString = "123450ABCab"
        Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

        Private Sub frmNewPatient_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

            ' AUTO GENERATE RANDOM IDs '
            Dim random As New Random
            Dim id As Integer
            id = (random.Next(100000000, 1000000000))
            txtID.Text = id
    End sub
End Class
```

Comment: DB IDs need to be unique not random.  Encoding information into an ID is generally a bad idea (the result will be a string, not a number).  You can always use SQL to create something like that from 2 columns such as Year and ID

Comment: Why not generate your `id` and then concatenate it using `txtID.Text = Format(Today, "yy") & "-" & id`